# All files are sent with myme text/html, ignoring the header function writeHead on server node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-headers

i come with a question about my code nodejs server, which when sent a header but in the console I aparesca correctly, the browser ignores it and takes everything as text / html, Here I add them what is the code of my router

```
var path = require("path");
var fs = require('fs');
var root = "www";

    function enrutar(manejador,ruta,respuesta){
        console.log("Voy a rutear algo para "+ruta);

        var extencion = path.extname(ruta);
        console.log("la extencion es: ",extencion);

        if(typeof manejador[ruta] === 'function'){
            manejador[ruta](respuesta);
        }
        else
        {
            switch (extencion)
            {
                // get the html
                case '.html':
                fs.readFile(root + ruta, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) return send404(respuesta);
                    respuesta.writeHead(200, { 'content-Type': 'text/html' });
                    respuesta.write(data);
                    respuesta.end();
                });
                break;

                // get the script that /public/chatclient.html references
                case '.js':
                fs.readFile(root + ruta, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) return send404(respuesta);
                    respuesta.writeHead(200, { 'content-Type': 'text/javascript' });
                    respuesta.write(data);
                    respuesta.end();
                });
                break;
                // get the styles that /public/chatclient.html references
                case '.css':
                fs.readFile(root + ruta, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) return send404(respuesta);
                    respuesta.writeHead(200, { "Content-type" : "text/css"});
                    respuesta.end(data);
                    console.log("Sirvo css: ",respuesta);
                });
                break;

                case '.json':
                fs.readFile(root + ruta, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) return send404(respuesta);
                    respuesta.writeHead(200, { 'content-Type': 'application/json' });
                    respuesta.write(data);
                    respuesta.end();
                });
                break;

                case '.jpg':
                fs.readFile(root + ruta, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) return send404(respuesta);
                    respuesta.writeHead(200, {'content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
                    respuesta.write(data);
                    respuesta.end();
                });
                break;

                case '.mp3':
                fs.readFile(root + ruta, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) return send404(respuesta);
                    respuesta.writeHead(200, {'content-Type': 'text/html'});
                    respuesta.write(data);
                    respuesta.end();
                });
                break;

                case '.png':
                fs.readFile(root + ruta, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) return send404(respuesta);
                    respuesta.writeHead(200, {'content-Type': 'image/png'});
                    respuesta.write(data);
                    respuesta.end();
                });
                break;

                default: send404(res);
            }
        }

        var registro = fs.createWriteStream('registro.txt',{'flags':'a'});
        registro.write(ruta + '\n');
    }

    function send404(res){
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write("404 Objeto no encontrado :c", 'utf8');
        res.end();
    }

    exports.enrutar = enrutar;
```

and this is my server code:

```
var servidor = require('http');
var url = require('url');


function iniciar(enrutar, manejador){
    function arrancaServidor(peticion,respuesta){

        var ruta = url.parse(peticion.url).pathname.replace("%20"," ");

        if(ruta == "/"){
            ruta = "index.html";
        }

        var contenido = enrutar(manejador,ruta,respuesta);  
    }
    servidor.createServer(arrancaServidor).listen(80);
}

exports.iniciar = iniciar;
```

all answers have a header like this:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://localhost/css/style.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:es-419,es;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:_manga_session=WkNYb1AvMFJUME9qVmRrSUtHbXBZbnRwQXRrUndZL01SeUE2K1BwYkh5dGt6M25xSllwcXk2THhWSjZpWUFQV1cyZzcxamRnTzVqMFBFRUlrNHAwM1NQWU9ML1dvY2V6TkZESnpETmhueUdQZFMyWDJZdDhLVmt2cVlvWVBmMTRHYmhIejZieW9rS0lGQWowbTJ5OXdnPT0tLTJyWksxa2w5N0dwQVVaVFp0bkRkYXc9PQ%3D%3D--069e1756464d40f36e80a86f386e9cab9f9cd014; PHPSESSID=1aj908onjk1g3muvkanhoq4s10
Host:localhost
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost/demo.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 04 Jul 2014 08:17:17 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

And took several days on this problem and I was beginning to despair hahaha, thank you very much in advance.

PD: Excuse my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself, is that running the server to the Packete `Supervisor` to avoid having to start it manually with each change. Not sure if `Supervisor` has some kind of cache because when you run the server with `node --debug` (and after almost reinstall browsers who had installed was desperate Understand me hahaha), it works.

Not sure if this incorrectly using `Supervisor` because according to me, review changes server.js entire folder is missing or if only changes to the file ... either way thank you very much to those who gave the task of reading my question and keep up this quality of work :).